# Style css width:inherit?

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

I have some elements that are getting out of my parent `div`. Why?

Here is what I have

CSS:

```css
.lightbox img {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.viewer-v3.lightbox {
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.viewer img {
    margin-top: 2%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}


.borderLightbox
{
    border:#cccccc;
    border-width:1%;
    border-top-style:none;
    border-right-style:solid; 
    border-bottom-style :solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    position:relative;

    width: 80%;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}




.headerLightbox
{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border:#cccccc;
    border-width:1%;
    width: inherit;
    float:left;
    border-top-style:solid;

    border-right-style:none; 
    border-bottom-style :none;

    border-left-style:none;
}

.actionsLightbox
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

And HTML:

```html
<div class="viewer-v3 lightbox">
    <div class="borderLightbox">

        <div class="headerLightbox">
            HEADER

            <div class="actionsLightbox">
               ACTIONS
            </div>

        </div>

        <img class="image" src="http://www.goldbergjones-or.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/how-to-get-divorced.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with headers and action always getting out of parent `div`. I don't know why, because all the widhts are inherited from parent `div`, and my header and actions `div` are always getting out of parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE 3

The solution is to add a content box around the content and let him have the scrollbar.

See this [example](http://jsbin.com/AkAhawa/7/edit).

#### HTML

```
<div class="viewer-v3 lightbox">
   <div class="borderLightbox">
       <div class="headerLightbox">
           HEADER
           <div class="actionsLightbox">
               ACTIONS
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="contentbox">
           <img class="image" src="http://www.goldbergjones-or.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/how-to-get-divorced.jpg">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.lightbox img {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.viewer-v3.lightbox {
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.viewer img {
    margin-top: 2%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.contentbox {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}


.borderLightbox
{
    border:#cccccc;

    border-width:1%;
    border-top-style:none;

    border-right-style:solid; 
    border-bottom-style :solid;

    border-left-style:solid;
    position:relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.headerLightbox
{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border:#cccccc;
    border-width:1%;
    width: inherit;
    float:left;
    border-top-style:solid;

    border-right-style:none; 
    border-bottom-style :none;

    border-left-style:none;
}

.actionsLightbox
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Understood your requirements, and I am afraid it is not possible.

The reason for the behavior is that `.viewer` gets a scrollbar, therefore its content width won't equal to the width of the body.

Thus: 80% of viewer != 80% of body (which is what you have for the `position: fixed` `.header`)

To see what I mean, just remove the `height: 100%` from the `.viewer`, and everything pops into place (only that `.viewer` won't be scrollable which is a no go)

### UPDATE 1

If you need it fixed: do pixel sizes help?

```
.borderLightbox {
   width: 500px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/AkAhawa/5

### ORIGINAL

It is because you have the `position: fixed;` property.

Think about it as that takes it out of the context of its parent and makes the body its parent, so from then on, positioning and sizing the `.headerLightbox` will be relative to the viewport.

If you wish to simply display the header with `width: 100%` (regarding its parent) then use

```
.headerLightbox
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I need fixed, because it has to be fixed on top, when scolling the page, this is now the answer, got any ideas?

Comment: try that width: 100%; and see what will happen?

Comment: Updated answer, the problem is with the scrollbar that appears in `.viewer` and modifies the available width for the children..

Comment: There is only the alternative from UPDATE 3, but that is a bit ugly as well with scrollbars inside the border element.